# how do i run main file which function is store in another file and also the header file too?

Tags: c

//  mainheader.h

```
int square(int b);
```

// maiNfunction.c

```
#include"mainheader.h"
#include<stdio.h>


int square(int b)
{
  int y;
  y= b*b;
  return (y);
}
```

//=====maiN.c file

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<stdlib.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include"mainheader.h"
 #include"maiNfunction.h"

 main(void)
 {
    //int SizeOfData,j;

      int i,z;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            z=square(i);
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }

}
```

how do i run this program in ubuntu?

Comment: did you try ./maiN.c in the terminal while in the folder with the files?

Comment: its saying permission denied

Comment: then you need to 'sudo chmod 777 [file1] [file2] ...' then run it

Comment: i cant get exactly wat u r saying wat i hav to do?

Comment: you need to give execute privileges on that file in order to run it. If you run chmod from sudo with the 777 parameter (that gives read, write and execute to everyone) on that file, you will then be able to run it from any user using ./filename

Comment: @iffy thats not necessary you are on the wrong way...

Comment: @TuKsn why is that?

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7110046

Answer (score 1):

This looks like c sourcecode, which needs to be compiled first.

```
gcc -o programName maiNfunction.c maiN.c
```

This creates an executable file, which already should have the permission to be executed. You can run it by typing:

```
./programName
```

Maybe you should consider reading more of the compiler documentation.

In case, you didn't do that yet, you of course need to install a compiler (e.g. gcc).